# Pre-built login / authentication component for a php app?

Tags: php, security, ssl, authentication

I know this question has been asked before, but I haven't found any answers that seem ideal.

I have a php app that needs a login system.  I'm no crypto expert by any means, and I am wary of reinventing the wheel, which has doubtless been invented many times already, and very well.

I'm wondering if anyone is aware of a good authentication component which can easily be integrated into an existing script, which adheres to all best practices and which, when combined with an ssl login, will satisfy all *reasonable* requirements for being secure.

I would prefer a stand-alone component, as opposed to having to setup an entire framework of some sort.  (The rest of the app does not use a framework, and I dislike the idea of having to use one, just for auth.)

Thanks for your help,

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth which is both framework-agnostic and database-agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use LDAP ?, it's standard, secured and fairly easy.

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5032010.html

Answer (score 1):

Zend Framework is designed so you can use individual components without using the MVC part of the framework. You can use the authentication module (zend_auth) which has only one hard dependency (zend_exception). You might want to use zend_acl, zend_session (requires zend_loader) and/or zend_db (requires zend_config, zend_registry, zend_loader) too depending on your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article.  The system works great and it's amazingly well thought out.

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/Building-a-CHAP-Login-System-An-ObjectOriented-Approach/